# Sub domain "www" not showing up on sub domain url

Tags: url, web, subdomain

I have created sub domain as `example.domain.com` on godaddy but when I put url as `www.example.subdomain.com` it throws me an error

```
This webpage is not available
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

but when I use as `http://example.subdomain.com` it works. Why is this so?

Comment: You are missing a DNS entry for the `www` part. You should fix that with a `CNAME` or `A` record for `www.example.subdomain.com`. Be warned that you may run into another issue where the server will not have a vhost set up for `www.example.subdomain.com`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to handle the sub-domains *example.subdomain.com* and *www.example.subdomain.com* as if they were two completely different sub-domains.

Fun fact:
It's even possible to create sub-domains like "this.is.my.crazy.subdomain.com"!

Comment: I'd go a bit further than this: from a technical perspective, example.subdomain.com and www.example.subdomain.com *are* completely different sub-domains. Thus, you need separate DNS and vhost entries for each, and if you're using SSL you either need a separate certificate for each, or a single cert with an alternate subject name extension for the second domain name.